# Angular passing index from parent to child in nested *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to display content with bunch of nested *ngFor loops and I want to keep track of the index of previous ngFor loop as a parent index. I couldn't find a way to pass the index of previous loop to the current one.

Here is what I try (doesn't work):

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of content; index as i" > 
    <span>{{parent.name}} index - {{i}}</span>
        <div *ngFor="let child of parent.childreen; i as parentIndex, index as i"  >
            <span>{{child.name}} index - {{i}} parentIndex - {{parentIndex}}   </span>
            <div *ngFor="let child of child.childreen; i as parentIndex, index as i">
                <span>{{child}} index - {{i}} parentIndex - parentIndex</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way that enable me to add previous `index` to `parentIndex` variable like above?

This is the example output that I want to achieve.

```
Parent 1 index - 0
Child 1.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 0
Child 1.1.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 0
Child 1.1.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 0
Child 1.1.3 index - 2 parentIndex - 0
Child 1.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 0
Child 1.2.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 1
Child 1.2.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 1
Child 1.2.3 index - 2 parentIndex - 1

Parent 2 index - 1
Child 2.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 1
Child 2.1.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 0
Child 2.1.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 0
Child 2.1.3 index - 2 parentIndex - 0
Child 2.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 1
Child 2.2.1 index - 0 parentIndex - 1
Child 2.2.2 index - 1 parentIndex - 1
Child 2.2.3 index - 2 parentIndex - 1
```

Here is the example of object that I used

```
  content: any[] = [
    {
      name: "Parent 1",
      childreen: [        
        {
        name: "Child 1.1",
        childreen: ["Child 1.1.1", "Child 1.1.2", "Child 1.1.3"]
      }, {
        name: "Child 1.2",
        childreen: ["Child 1.2.1", "Child 1.2.2", "Child 1.2.3"]
      }]
    }, {
      name: "Parent 2",
      childreen: [
        {
          name: "Child 2.1",
          childreen: ["Child 2.1.1", "Child 2.1.2", "Child 2.1.3"]
        }, {
          name: "Child 2.2",
          childreen: ["Child 2.2.1", "Child 2.2.2", "Child 2.2.3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use different local variable names for each `*ngFor`'s index.

```html
<div *ngFor="let parent of content; index as i">
  <span>{{parent.name}} index - {{i}}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let child of parent.childreen; index as j">
    <span>{{child.name}} index - {{j}} parentIndex - {{i}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let child of child.childreen; index as k">
      <span>{{child}} index - {{k}} parentIndex - {{i}} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

#### Update

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-usbqy6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes I figure out that but I think it would me more manageable if I use same variable name for all of them. Is there any way that I can implement this as I described above?

Comment: Using same variable name wouldn't work. It would reset the value in each `*ngFor`'s scope. But I don't understand one thing yet. You wish to have `parentIndex - 1` in it's iterating it's first element?

Comment: `parentIndex - 1` seem to be randomly inserted in the output expected. Are you sure the expected output is correct?

Comment: I added the the output manually, I checked it seems ok. Basically I want a reference of the parent object index in my child objects to do some operations afterwards. So if parent have index 1, children will have `parentIndex - 1` and their own indexes. I have too many for loops to keep track each index with different variable thats why I want an approach as described above.

Comment: I've added a working example based on your input object. You need to understand that each `*ngFor` would expand into it's own `<ng-template>` block in the DOM. And each block will have it's own scope. So each index must have a unique name for it be referenced in nested `<ng-template>` blocks. If there are too many `*ngFor`s then perhaps it has to be adjusted to reduce the number of blocks. Apart from that there is no way to access one `*ngFor`'s index in it's nested blocks.